# How to use a comparison operator (like a BETWEEN clause) on dates in JSON using PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql

I have a json column called `myfield` that holds a json document:

```
{"createDate": 1448067864151, "id": 1, "name": "hello"}
```

I can extract the createDate like so:

```
SELECT 
myfield->'createDate' AS dt
FROM mytable
```

I can view the date properly using JavaScript

```
console.log(new Date(1447734116009));
> 2015-11-17T04:21:56.009Z
```

How do I accomplish something like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM mytable
WHERE myfield->'createDate' BETWEEN '2015-11-1' AND '2015-11-10'
```

I would also like to use the greater than and less than operators on the extracted date field.

```
SELECT
*
FROM mytable
WHERE myfield->'createDate' > '2015-11-1'
```

I'm not certain how to structure this with the JSON extensions in the PostgreSQL query language.

Based on [this help doc,](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) it doesn't appear that Postgres even has a date operator for JSON.  If it doesn't have one, is there some other way (like with a custom function) to convert the serialized date into some other format (ISO format perhaps?) and then use the regular PostgreSQL date operators on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createDate` key obviously holds a value in Unix epoch format: seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00. PostgreSQL and Java both use this same format (although Java uses millisecond precision on an `int64` while PostgreSQL uses seconds in a `float64`) so you can easily convert the `json` value to a PostgreSQL `timestamp with time zone` and then apply the default date\time operators on it:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE to_timestamp(myfield->'createDate' * 0.001) BETWEEN '2015-11-1' AND '2015-11-10';
```

More in general, PostgreSQL does not have *any* operators specifically for `json` values. You always have to unpack your `json` document and then work directly with the values, possibly after casting them to a specific type if an implicit interpretation is not useful (e.g. if the value is all [0-9] then interpret as `integer`), as is the case here. Insofar as I am aware, the same is true for Java (and probably every other language/framework).